# SELECT count rows from 2 tables and sum the results

Tags: php, count, mysql-num-rows

I have the PHP code:

```
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM `table_1`");
$result = mysqli_num_rows($query);

$queryTwo = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM `table_2`");
$resultTwo = mysqli_num_rows($queryTwo);

$number =  $result + $resultTwo;
return $number;
```

**The point is that sometimes, the `$number` variable is returning NULL,
 when it should not supposed to do that.**

I have always rows in those 2 tables, and the returned result should not be NULL, ever.

Is this a correct approach to sum the number of rows from 2 tables? I don`t understand why sometimes I get NULL instead of a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I would suggest you to do it like

```
  select ( select count(*) from Table1 ) + ( select count(*) from Table2 ) 
  as total_rows
```

executing this query and getting the value of `total_rows` will return you true result

Or you can create a stored procedure to do the same thing. as explained below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Test
AS
-- Create two integer values
DECLARE @tableOneCount int, @tableTwoCount int

-- Get the number of rows from the first table
SELECT @tableOneCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1
                         WHERE WhereClause)
SELECT @tableTwoCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2
                         WHERE WhereClause)

-- Return the sum of the two table sizes
SELECT TotalCount = @tableOneCount + @tableTwoCount
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you go with only one query like this:
you will have the result directly in one step and it will avoid contacting the DB twice to fetch intermediate result and it will also simplify your program!

```
SELECT 
(select count(*) from table_1)
+
(select count(*) from table_2)
```